# Can't get NAV 2015 and 2016 to work side by side in Management Console

Tags: installation, dynamics-nav

I have installed the 2015 version and then the 2016 version of Microsoft Dynamics NAV. Everything works fine besides the Management Console.

When I install NAV 2015, I get version 8 of the Management Console. When I install NAV 2016, it replaces the old (version 8.0) Management Console for NAV 2015 with Management Console 9.0 for NAV 2016.

The problem here is that I can't manage the version 8.0 instances for NAV 2015, only 9.0 instances for NAV 2016 in Management Console.

How can I manage my 8.0 Instances/server for NAV 2015? Is it possible to somehow separate the installation of Management console 8.0 from 9.0??

I'm talking about the administration tool. This is the error I get:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same article of the steps below [[1](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)], it is possible to arrive to a **second site** [[2](http://www.waldo.be/2015/10/14/fix-nav2015-administration-shell-after-nav-2016-installation/)], where Waldo gives a power shell script for a *one click* solution.

References

1. [NAV 2016 installation overwrites NAV 2015 Administration Tool](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)
2. [Fix NAV2015 Administration Shell after NAV 2016 installation](http://www.waldo.be/2015/10/14/fix-nav2015-administration-shell-after-nav-2016-installation/)

---

**Some words more**

> The reason that NAV 2015 Administration Tool is actually starting NAV 2016 is because of a registry entry.

You can read in [[1](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)]

> The NAV 2015 and NAV 2016 Administration Tool both point to this registry key:
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE}**

Always in [[1](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)] it is proposed a solution in two main steps, modifying the problematic registry key and the relative reference in a file (`Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server.msc`).
The proposed steps are reported below and implemented in a script available in a second site [[2](http://www.waldo.be/2015/10/14/fix-nav2015-administration-shell-after-nav-2016-installation/)].
The logic is to modify the key for the version 8.0 instead of the 9.0 and to write the consequent patches relative to the key itself, the `NAV/90` in `NAV/80`, and `9.0.0.0` in `8.0.0.0`.

**Steps**

1. With the registry editor, find the key and export it to a file.
   Then  Modify the exported file

   > Search for all occurences of  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\90 and change it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80
   >
   > Search for Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.ManagementUI, Version=9.0.0.0 and change it to Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.ManagementUI, Version=8.0.0.0
   >
   > Change all occurences of BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE to BA484C41-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE. (Only changed 8th character here, you can even choose to replace the complete GUID).

   and import again the modified file into the registry (double clicking...)
2. Run a text editor as Administrator and open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80\RoleTailored Client\Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server.msc`
   There

   > Change all occurences of `BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE` to `BA484C41-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE`
   >   Notice this is the same GUID as changed in step 1. There are 4 occurences.
   >   Then save the file and exit.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue.

> The reason that NAV 2015 Administration Tool is actually starting NAV 2016 is because of a registry entry.

You can read in [[1](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)]

> The NAV 2015 and NAV 2016 Administration Tool both point to this registry key:
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE}**

For a solution follow the steps of [[1](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)].

**Steps**

1. With the registry editor, find the key and export it to a file.
   Then  Modify the exported file

   > Search for all occurences of  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\90 and change it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80
   >
   > Search for Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.ManagementUI, Version=9.0.0.0 and change it to Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.ManagementUI, Version=8.0.0.0
   >
   > Change all occurences of BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE to BA484C41-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE. (Only changed 8th character here, you can even choose to replace the complete GUID).

   and import again the modified file into the registry (double clicking...)
2. Run a text editor as Administrator and open the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\80\RoleTailored Client\Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server.msc`
   There

   > Change all occurences of `BA484C42-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE` to `BA484C41-ED9A-4bc1-925F-23E64E686FCE`
   >   Notice this is the same GUID as changed in step 1. There are 4 occurences.
   >   Then save the file and exit.

   References:

   1. [fix nav2015 administration shell after nav 2016 installation](http://kauffmann.nl/index.php/2015/10/07/nav-2016-installation-overwrites-nav-2015-administration-tool/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.